# Using a comma before "but"

Tags: punctuation, conjunctions, commas

I was once told by an English professor that a comma should never be used before *but* in a sentence. For years, I have followed her advice but sometimes I just feel like it just *needs* to be there. On the other hand, my brain also tells me that the word *but* is, in a sense, performing the same function as a comma in the sentence.

Does anyone know if there is a rule for this?

Comment: For the record: "For years I have followed her advice, but sometimes..." would have been completely correct.

Comment: I must have had the same teacher! The comma with 'but' is redundant. 'But' provides the pause in the sentence so only rarely, for additional emphasis of a pause, might a comma be needed with 'but.'

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[Larry Trask's Penguin Guide to Punctuation](http://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0140513663) makes it clear that it is [permissible to use a comma before 'but'](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node11.html#SECTION00042000000000000000). The OWL Perdue Writing lab [does the same](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/01/). The BBC Learning English site [likewise](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv258.shtml).

You were misinformed.

Answer (score 36):

That rule sounds very odd. Few people would never use a comma before *but*. I believe many follow this rule: **use a comma before *but* if (and only if) it introduces an independent sentence**. This applies to the other coordinating conjunctions too (*and, or,* and *so*).

> She liked him but refused to marry
>   him.
>
> She liked him, but she refused to
>   marry him.

I find that I do not always stick to this rule: I sometimes use a comma before *but-dependent* when I feel a pause would somehow improve the flow of the sentence (vague, I know).

In very short (informal?) sentences, the comma is sometimes left out regardless, though some might object to this:

> It's true but it sucks.

Answer (score 4):

Visit the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), and search for *but*. You will find many sentences where a comma precedes *but*.

This is a useless, artificial rule, one of the type that misguided English teachers love so much to invent.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the actual sentence. Often *but* is used before a contrasting element and thus should be set off by a comma. This conflicts with the *no comma* rule before the conjunction for dependent clauses - to be on the safe side use comma before *but*, and convert a dependent clause into an independent one by adding a subject.

Example:

*I can do most of the things the software would do for me but am unclear on the symbiosis of it all.*

should be

*I can do most of the things the software would do for me, but I am unclear on the symbiosis of it all*

to avoid the conflict.

[Source (archived version)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130603183624/https://www.irosetta.com/questions/can-am-stand-alone-part-two).

Answer (score 3):

General rule of thumb: if "but" is used as a coordinating conjunction (one that combines two independent clauses), then it should be accompanied by the preceding comma.

Answer (score 2):

The word may make a comma semantically redundant, but syntactically it aids readability.

Comment: I completely agree.

Comment: Except that this should read 'The word [_but_] may make a comma  redundant as an aid to identifying the structure used, but prosodically it aids readability.'

Answer (score 2):

In my first college course, I was taught to use a comma before "but" when it introduced an independent clause. I used to slap commas in intuitively, but I'm glad I've learned how to use them properly.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is not a simple answer here. This is why some of us were taught to use comma before 'but', and some of us were not.

Generally speaking, in the UK, writers tend not put a comma before the conjunction. In the US, however, writers tend to use a comma.

The links below will give more info:

- [Using a Comma before "And"](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/commas_before_conjunctions.htm)
- [Using Commas in Lists](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/commas_in_lists.htm)

Comment: This isn't really a link-sharing site so much as it's a give the answer and then explain it site, but I'm guessing you came from a different se?

Comment: I googled exactly the same question and found the links above. Then found this thread where no one said about the differences between the UK and the US styles, which make perfect sense to me. I hope, I pretty clearly presented info I wanted in the first four sentences, and then gave the links for those interested to learn more. What's wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

My rule is to avoid commas before conjunctions unless the conjunction indroduces a clearly new idea. I often type a comma before a conjunction only to remove it when I realise it divides the text unnecessarily.