# Should I use a comma before "and" or "or"?

Tags: punctuation, commas, conjunctions, oxford-comma, and-or

Is using a comma then an "and" or an "or" after it proper punctuation?
Example:

> - I fell over, and hurt my knee.
> - Should I go, or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a comma before "but"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28277/using-a-comma-before-but)

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Whether it is correct to use a comma before a coordinating conjunction ("and", "but", "or", "nor", "for", "yet", "so") depends on the situation. There are three primary uses of conjunctions:

1. When a coordinating conjunction is used to connect two independent clauses, a comma is **always** used. Examples:

   - I hit my brother with a stick, and he cried.
   - The rain stopped, and the sun came out again.
   - Should I eat dinner, or should I play a game?
2. When a coordinating conjunction is used to connect a dependent clause, a comma is **never** used. This includes both of your given examples. Other examples:

   - The boy ran to his room and cried.
   - Frank is a healthy and active child.
   - Should I eat dinner or play a game?
3. When a coordinating conjunction is used to connect three or more items or clauses, a comma is **optional** (though I personally prefer to use one). Examples:

   - I bought cheese, crackers, and drinks at the store.
   - Should I eat dinner, play a game, or go to the store?

Comment: See also the Oxford/Serial comma debate (your point 3): [Serial comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma).

Comment: I agree with your examples, but I think the labels on 1 and 2 could be improved. The first group is about *independent* clauses, not *main* clauses. The second one is about *non-independent* or *dependent* clauses, not *subordinate* clauses (they are dependent because they are elliptical).

Comment: @Cerberus Thank you for the suggestions. I've modified my answer to reflect them.

Comment: @rintaun: I agree with the main points of your answer but disagree with using __always__ and __never__. Between very short and closely connected independent clauses, the comma can be omitted. ("He played the guitar and she sang.") In compound predicates, a comma is not usually used, though it may be needed to avoid confusion or indicate a pause. ("She recognized the man who entered the room, and gasped" vs. "She recognized the man who entered the room and gasped.") _CMOS 6.32, 6.34 (15th ed.)_ It would be better to use the word __usually__.

Comment: Also, in your second point, "cried" is not a dependent clause. It _cannot_ be a dependent clause because it does not have a subject. It is just part of a compound predicate. Here is an example of a sentence with one independent and once dependent clause: "The boy ran to his room because he was crying."

Comment: When listing things in German, we never use the comma before the `and`. However, thanks to the pointed out article that talks about [Resolving ambiguity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma#Resolving_ambiguity) I see the argument: The `and` can connect the last both items in context - as if it would be one item from the listing. However, Germans never *think* like that, we got used to utilize the last `and` to make clear that the last element of the list follows. And if there is a connected pair, we use and again: Rot, *grün und gelb* und orange.

Comment: I would have thought that in 'Frank is a healthy and active child' 'and' connects adjectives, not clauses.  Surely there is no reason to read 'Frank is a healthy child and Frank is an active child'.

Comment: @Toothrot That's a great point -- that is indeed not connecting clauses. That said, it's actually the description of #2 that's flawed... It also includes connecting exactly two items, in contrast to #3, which covers the "three or more" case.

Comment: People who didn't/don't spend time thinking about English grammar tend to think of comma usage as an arbitrary rule that just needs to be memorized, but as @KaiNoack pointed out, it's about [resolving ambiguity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma#Resolving_ambiguity). If you're writing a sentence and are unsure about comma omission (or addition), consider the possible ways in which your sentence can be interpreted, and try to remove any ambiguity which can leave your reader misunderstanding your point... which is, after all, *the* point.

Answer (score 6):

Getting comma usage with *and* and *or* can be tricky sometimes, and even the best of us will mess it up once in a while.

Here's a good guide: http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp

And some examples:

- *I fell over **and** hurt my knee.*
- *I fell over, hurt my knee **, and** got stitches.*
- *I like the colors red **and** blue.*
- *I like the colors red, blue **, and** purple.*
- *You can buy an apple, a pear **, or** an orange.*
- *I can go **or** stay - which would you prefer?*

When used in a list, *and* and *or* never take a comma when the list has two items; when it has more, it is generally a good idea to use the comma.

When used as a conjunction it is generally a good idea to use the comma (unless the phrases are very short).

Answer (score 5):

"I went to Japan and returned in 2009" is correct but rather unspecific. It could imply either "I went [say, in 2003] and returned in 2009" or "I went and returned in 2009". The comma in "I went to Japan, and returned in 2009" points to the former; With two commas, "I went to Japan, and returned, in 2009" definitely implies the latter.