# When can a comma be used before the word 'and'?

Tags: punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use a comma before “and” or “or”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30516/should-i-use-a-comma-before-and-or-or)

Is it appropriate and/or advisable to use a comma before 'and' in some situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be appropriate and advisable.  Some examples from Carey's "Mind the Stop" are helpful (p49 in the 1980 reprint of the Penguin edition):

> - It is impossible, and indeed undesirable, to lay down hard-and-fast rules on this subject.
> - I stayed with him most of the afternoon and the next day, on going to see him again, found him a little better.

The first shows a case where the comma before *and* is very necessary, and the second shows a case where the absence of the comma leads you astray on first reading the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Commas before *and* are useful in cases where there are two independent clauses that require linkage; for example:

> A cat can climb trees, and it can climb curtains.
>
> [A cat can climb trees] + [A cat can climb curtains].