# Is the comma between "question" and "so" needed? If so, why?

Tags: grammar

I have come across this problem numerous times. I am unsure of why a comma is needed in phrases such as the one below — between the words "question" and "so."

*Our goal is to have the best answers to every question, so if you see questions or answers that can be improved, you can edit them.*

I know why the second comma is needed, but I am unaware of why the first comma is needed. Perhaps someone could be kind enough to answer my question and explain why the comma is needed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use a comma before "and" or "or"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30516/should-i-use-a-comma-before-and-or-or)

Comment: To give the reader time to finish processing the first part, and be clear-headed enough to take in the greater importance of the second part.

Answer (score 1):

It's needed because there's a natural pause, the way you'd pause if you were saying it aloud.

I think a long dash would be even more effective there:

*Our goal is to have the best answers to every question—so if you see questions or answers that can be improved, you can edit them.*

This also separates the sentence into its two natural sections.

Answer (score 0):

"So" is a coordinating conjunction, so there should always be a comma in front of it (the fanboys), unless it is followed by "that", then never put a comma.

Eg. I am writing this *so that* you will understand.

Comment: Hi, Emil, Just a heads-up. Did you read the linked question in my comment above? You misspelled "never".

Comment: I have to disagree. The coordinating conjunction "so" does not always need a comma before it. I know there's a reason as to why the comma is needed, but the reason you gave me is incorrect.