# Comma in coordinating conjunction that includes an if-clause

Tags: commas, coordinating-conjunctions

On the basis of [this Q&A](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30516/should-i-use-a-comma-before-and-or-or), I understand that my example sentence is a coordinating conjunction; however, I can't seem to figure out the relationship between the first clause, and the if-clause. Should there be a comma before the *or* and why?

> Please let me know your thoughts *(,)*or if you experience any trouble opening the attachment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should not be a comma.

A comma is used if the coordinating conjunction (e.g. *or*) separates two independent clauses. Example:

> *Please let me know your thoughts, or reach out if you experience any trouble opening the attachment.*

There you have two independent clauses in the imperative form—*let me know . . .* and *reach out . . .*

Your coordinating conjunction does not do that; instead it separates an independent clause from a dependent (*if*) clause. Yours can be understood like this:

> *Please let me know:*
>   *• your thoughts*
>   *or*
>   *• if you experience any trouble opening the attachment.*