# Comma placement in "developing cutting edge websites and previously video games"

Tags: conjunctions, commas

This is the opening line of my CV so I would like it to be correct. Would this be the correct place to put the comma? I've always been taught not to put a comma before *and*.

> I’m a talented and versatile programming and UI professional with 5 years of commercial experience in developing cutting-edge websites, and previously video games.

Comment: Related: [Comma before last item in a list](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/comma-before-last-item-in-a-list)

Comment: "To my parents, the Pope and Mother Teresa."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comma should be omitted altogether if you are referring to *A and B*.

> I’m a talented and versatile programming and UI professional with 5
>   years of commercial experience in developing cutting-edge websites and
>   previously video games.

However one may introduce an optional pair of *bracketing commas* to set off the weak interruption *previously*.

> I’m a talented and versatile programming and UI professional with 5
>   years of commercial experience in developing cutting-edge websites
>   and, previously, video games.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I think that the sentence reads better if the "previously" is presented as a clause. "and, previously, video games" reads more naturally to me.

Comment: I agree with @Jasper that "previously" should be weakly bracketed with commas.

However, the improved punctuation does not remove an ambiguity. Does the OP mean that he has 5 years of commercial experience in developing cutting-edge websites and, previously, 5 years of commercial experience in developing video games? With the sentence as it is, I am left unsure about the nature and length of the video game experience the OP has.

It might be better to write something like: "with 3? years of experience in developing video games, followed by 5 years of commercial experience in developing cutting

Comment: I have purposely left it ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/28277/8183) question addresses a similar problem, except with the conjunction "but", not "and" as here.

Basically, the same principles apply. Commas originally weren't used before conjunctions, but now they are. Thus, there is nothing wrong with your adding the comma behind "and". In fact, I would suggest:

> ...developing cutting-edge websites, and previously, video games.

Hope that helps!

Comment: So, you don't find anything strange in "to my parents, the Pope and Mother Theresa," do you?